# Is an "Underwater Metropolis" possible today?

Tags: science-based, technology, cities, underwater

Im sure some are familiar with Bioshock's "Rapture City," a (somewhat) successful underwater city that was able to maintain stability and house an entire population. But, using current technology and engineering, could we (and how) construct a city off the west coast of the United States that:

1. Is located on the side of an underwater ravine.
2. Has a max depth of 400 meters
3. Can inhabit max of 30,000 people
4. Has a source of food and water (preferably not imported from the mainland)
5. Adequate defense systems
6. Standard city departments (Education, law enforcement, public works, etc.)

   Keep in mind, however unrealistic, that budget is practically unlimited, but stay reasonable.

NOTE: If any further clarification is needed, let me know. The more critique,the better

Comment: If nobody feels like attacking your city, then pretty much any defense systems are adequate. But if you pick a fight with superpowers, you're probably in trouble.

Comment: This world, luckily, doesn't have superpowers. I mentioned the defense system because I considered the rather "wet" environment to have an affect on attack/defense of the city @armadillo

Comment: This may not have been clear, but I meant "superpowers" like the United States: like "hegemony," not Superman. How much of a defense force you need depends on who's mad at you. Nobody bombs [Sealand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principality_of_Sealand). And being underwater complicates things in that respect, like you mentioned. I can't answer your question, but it makes me want to watch SeaQuest DSV...

Comment: Why would you have a city there? Do the people live under pressure or does the habitat have to resist pressure?

Comment: @NathanHardy I would say that it would not be possible, simply because the economics would require a super power to build. At 400m, you need to withstand ~40ATM of pressure. In space, you only really need to withstand ~1ATM of pressure. This is structurally 40 times harder than building the ISS, and that took the combined resources of the international community to build.

Comment: @Aron: I think you're missing why exactly a space station is so difficult to build maintain: because getting there is hard and getting heavy things in orbit is enormously expensive. In an underwater structure you don't have to worry about weight and transporting costs are about as low as they get.

Comment: @fgysin Au contra. Yes energetically, it is much more expensive to move into orbit. That does not mean that there are other costs. Consider the construction of the structures (if you can call it that, given how ISS was assembled). Very few submarines could work construction (tightening a nut for example) at that depth. A fleet of ships comparable to a US task force would be involved in the construction. Then add the shore-side support required to support the fleet, and you have a nation's worth of economy supporting the venture.

Comment: @Aron: Oh yes, it will be quite a venture - I never wanted to call that into question. Just that it is considerably easier than building a big structure in orbit.

Comment: @fgysin I would say that the engineering challenges are no less difficult. Astronauts spend hours to do simple maintenance that equates to 'stepping outside and screwing in a dozen bolts', simply because movement is so hard in zero-G and in a space suit. A similar dive suit would be impossible to move in.

Comment: @Aron I don't see any reason why we couldn't just send robots down to build stuff. With todays technology, nuclear attack submarines are already able to dive down past the 400m mark (Maximum estimated is probably closer to 800m) - The main reason they don't go further is because the pressure would collapse the hull, but that's because there's air for the crew. I see no reason why we can't design robots to do the job of building things at that depth. Electronics clearly work at that depth.

Comment: @Aron: We're not talking the Mariana Trench, its 'just' 400m max... There exist suits that can work at that depth since the 1980ies! `The ADS can be used for very deep dives of up to 2,300 feet (700 m) for many hours[...]` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_diving_suit

Comment: @Aify I am not saying you couldn't. But given that the typical submarine robot requires an entire support ship to be built around it, and that you need multiple robots to build a city. You then have to remember you need a small town to support just one ship. We are clearly talking about superpower level organization for this megaproject. But the OP already said that there were no superpowers in his world.

Comment: @Aron the superpowers the OP said didn't exist was never clarified whether or he meant "superman style" superpowers or not. Furthermore, his question clearly states "off the west coast of the US" - indicating our current world. The US **is a superpower**.  Seeing as they already have over 60 nuclear submarines in commission, this is not a hard task to accomplish.

Comment: I think it is technically possible to build an underwater city, but economically speaking, even if there is a shortage of land for whatever reason (natural increase of population or flooding due to global warming?), it would be much more cost effect to build a city floating on the sea then underwater. At least you don't need to handle the water pressure and oxygen flow.

Comment: I apologize to all for any confusions, but yes, there are still world powers, and this city falls under the domain of the United States. @armadillo

Comment: ^ @Aify i apologize again

Comment: ^ @Aron I apologize as well

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, this is completely possible today. In fact we already have large elements of it.

We have submarines and submersibles, we have diving gear. There are [underwater hotels](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=underwater%20hotel&espv=2&biw=1334&bih=764&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjahN7GzvfMAhVCDMAKHdHtC0kQsAQIJg).

You have two basic choices for the buildings:

1. You can be linked to the surface air and have routes to the surface. This has the advantage of letting you enter and leave while being dry and cheaper air circulation. Your buildings need to be strong enough to withstand the water pressure though.
2. You can pressurize the buildings to the same level as the water and just have open pools for access in and out. This has the advantage of letting you access the water around you from the buildings without needing airlocks but you need to pump down and pressurize all of your air. Anyone heading to the surface would spend a LOT of time in decompression.

In practice there would most likely be a combination of these, with buildings at the top linked to the surface and others deeper open to the water. Transition between these buildings could be done using air locks to equalize the pressure.

Note that the depth you mention (400m) is **just** inside the range of human survival. [The records for deep diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_diving#Depth_ranges_in_underwater_diving) at external pressure are around 432m. In practice you would most likely need most of your city higher (and at less pressure) than that as we just have no idea what the long term effects of living in those conditions would be.

The problems here aren't technical. They're practical and financial. Would you want to live in a steel can underwater breathing recirculating and pressurized air? Especially when doing so would be substantially more expensive than living on land.

We have the technology today to build this. What we don't have is the reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It's technically possible but not financially feasible but I see your budget is practically unlimited.

And it would always need power to generate oxygen from some type of water source. The hydrogen might be used as fuel also. Power would also be needed to make freshwater from sea water.

Any metal parts exposed to seawater would need constant upkeep as salt water is very hard on even the best metal parts we have today.

Any moving parts and water intakes and output tubes would need constant upkeep to keep barnacles and other creatures off them. Barnacles, algae, and seaweed are HUGE problems for water intake tubes today, especially near areas where nitrogen-rich runoff goes right into the ocean. Algae is less of a problem in deeper areas where there isn't much sunlight but barnacles and other "fixed" creatures like coral tend to be a problem at many depths.